# Detecting errors with CURL

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to parse a list of websites using cURL in PHP but am running into the issue of detecting any html errors encountered when getting back a response. According to the php manual, the below code snippet should help detect any errors (error means the page is useless for parsing so anything like a 404 or 500 is an error in my book) during the call:

```
if(curl_error($c)) {
    print_r( 'error:' . curl_error($curl));
}
```

The above code does work for 404 errors but is unable to catch 500 errors for example (there may be more errors it doesnt catch). I can of course use this:

```
$httpCode = curl_getinfo ( $curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
```

But then i would have to manually add checks to evaluate the variable and ignore the result if the result was a 500 or 404 or 401 etc. How can i simply and accurately ignore the responses which are not useful for parsing the website?

Comment: `if($httpCode == 200){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$wrong_http_codes = '^0|4.*|5.*$';
$http_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if (preg_match("/$wrong_http_codes/", $http_code) === 1) {
    echo 'Error';
}
```