# PHP cURL - not detecting errors?

Tags: php, curl, response, server

I'm having some weirdness with returning cURL response code errors. The following code, despite the remote host throwing a 404, does not cURL error. Why?

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.google.com/13ewsdasd'); //<-- definitely a 404
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
echo curl_exec($ch) ? 'All OK' : 'Error: '.curl_error($ch); //'All OK'
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713451/detecting-errors-with-curl) that suggested using `curl_get_Info` with the `CURL_INFO_HTTP_CODE` flag, but no joy there, either - that just gives me "0".

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.google.com/13ewsdasd'); //<-- still a 404
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); //<-- 0
```

I seem to recall issues detecting errors with cURL before. Am I missing something obvious? I just want to detect when the remote server throws a 404 or 500.

Another answer suggested doing this via `get_headers()`, but it seems silly to have to fire a second, separate request just to find out the response code of the first one.

Comment: because it's not a 404, it's a 301. redirects aren't errors. And for your second example, you never called curl_exec, so there's no error to report.

Comment: Urgh, really? Did I just do that? Thanks for pointing out my lack of attention. In the first example, though, even for bonafide 404s and 500s (i.e. ones I control, so I know they're being sent), it doesn't give me the error.

Comment: The first is not an error in curl's view. It managed to transfer the HTTP just fine, exactly the way you asked. As Marc B already said...